# C# Creating new instance or Overwrite?

Tags: c#, performance, memory, instance

I'm creating a C# Winform Application with SQL Server Database, in any form I declare a SqlCOnnection and a SqlCommand within the Form Class , but I start initializing in every method when needed.
and here is my code :

```
    public partial class DrinkIncomeForm : Form
    {

        #region Class Variables
        private string conString;
        private string queryP1;
        private string queryP2;
        private SqlConnection con;
        private SqlCommand cmd;
        private SqlDataAdapter myAdapter;
        private SqlDataReader myReader;
        private DataTable drinksIncomeTable;
        #endregion

        public DrinkIncomeForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         private void DrinkIncomeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyGymConString"].ConnectionString;
            LoadDrinksCombo();
            LoadCashierCombo();
            DrinkComBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            CashierComBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            LoadDrinksIncomeDGV();
        }
        private void DrinkComBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadDrinksIncomeDGV();
        }

        private void CashierComBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadDrinksIncomeDGV();
        }
        private void LoadDrinksIncomeDGV()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            queryP1 = "select TransID, DrinkName, Quantity, Price, Offer, format(TransDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')as TransDate, Cashier  from tblDrinksIncome ";
            queryP2 = " where 1=1 ";
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                if(DrinkComBox.SelectedIndex >0)
                {
                    queryP2 += " AND DrinkName=@drinkname";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@drinkname", DrinkComBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
                }
                if (CashierComBox.SelectedIndex >0)
                {
                    queryP2 += " AND Cashier=@cashier";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashier", CashierComBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
                }
                cmd.CommandText = "" + queryP1 + queryP2;
                myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                drinksIncomeTable = new DataTable();
                myAdapter.Fill(drinksIncomeTable);
                DrinksIncomeDGV.DataSource = drinksIncomeTable;
                con.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Database Error.");
            }
        }
    }
```

as u see in every time the user select from the ComboBoxes(Filters) new instances will be created.
my question here is is this has bad effects on memory and performance , and if so what is the better way to do this ? 
thanks :)

Comment: instance of what? i.e. what are the things that are concerning you? In reality, this is unlikely to be a problem on anything that isn't an inner-loop data-processing scenario. Since this appears to be UI-bound, I wouldn't even look at it - it is going to be irrelevant compared to the other things going on. Could it be optimized? sure. Will it matter? Probably not in the least. If you want to know: **measure it**. And if it *does* matter, it *probably* means you're showing too much data to the user to be useful, so: show less data!

Comment: and if it *does* turn out to matter, the first thing I'd say is: "stop using `DataTable`". It isn't helping you any for efficiency.

Comment: i'm concerning about instances of(DataTable,SqlConnection,SqlCommand) . in every time the user change filters the function LoadProductsIncome() will create new instances and i don't what will happen to the old ones ! and what can i use instead of DataTable ?

Comment: a `List<T>` of some POCO `T` is usually a safe bet these days - i.e. a `List<Customer>`, a `List<Order>` or whatever; perhaps look at "Dapper" for how to actually populate that without writing the code yourself

Comment: Don't create a `new SqlConnection` on every call, use a singleton pattern or keep the connection open for as long as the form is open. It's fine to create a `new SqlCommand` every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have little downgrades on performance, but it is good design.

But you should not store your connection in a member variable. but only in local variable. Best would be a `using(var s = new SqlConnection(..))`. This way you ensure the Connection is Disposed at the end of your method, and any reference to it should be lost, so it can be garbage collected. The same is valid for the SqlCommand.

So your only critical error, is not to call `Dispose`, you call only `Close`.

Comment: "But you should not store your connection in a member variable. but only in local variable." - that is highly contextual and subjective; either approach is valid depending on the scenario. Of course, if you're going to *new* it each time, then I'm 100% with you (an instance field only makes sense if it is being reused). Agree on the command, but then: I'd probably say that if you're touching the command API directly you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Good, you are more precise. Keeping the connection open or not really depends on the context. For the question of performance: everytime a new is slower. Just wanted to point out, you have to make a compromise, on Performance vs. software architecture. If you are aware of this, everything is fine. If you go async, one connection per thread, so most often per method, is the safer way.

Comment: if you go async, you need to stop thinking in terms of threads :) but, fundamentally: concurrent sharing of a connection is just as broken whether you use sync or async; so agree that if you're going concurrent you want scoped connections - I just don't think sync vs async is the thing that matteres there

Comment: yes i was worried about what will happen to the old instances, i wasn't sure that if it will get collected or not  ! now calling Dispose() after Close() will make sense ?

Comment: It's not a definite decision, wheter keeping the connection open or not is better. But at least, to improve you current solution, call dispose, and don't store the connection in your private field ! It will not be garbage collected, as long as it is stored.